# React: How to send data on Popup close?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this Popup that I built in my React app. It's, in a sense, another page inside the Popup. In this Popup, there is a list. There are no forms at all in this Popup window. I only have another popup inside this popup with a submission form that adds another item to the list.

Therefore, what I'm attempting to do is to submit the list to the Parent component when I click on the "Close" button to close the Popup window. How do I do that?

Here's my code:

SingleBox.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SecurityForm from "../SecurityForm/index";
import PriceForm from "../PriceForm/index";

export default class SingleSecuritybox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        showPopup: false,
        showPricePopup: false, //don't show popup
        pricelist: this.props.price
    };
  }

  /* toggle and close popup edit form window */
  togglePopup = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      showPopup: !prevState.showPopup
    }));
  };

  togglePricePopup = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      showPricePopup: !prevState.showPricePopup
    }));
  };

  /* handles edit current security form submissions */
  handleEditSecuritySubmission = editSecurity => {
    const { editCurrentSecurity, id } = this.props;

    this.togglePopup();
    editCurrentSecurity({ ...editSecurity, id });

  };

  updatePrice = updatePrice => {
    const { updatePriceList, id } = this.props;

    this.togglePricePopup();

    updatePriceList({...updatePrice, id});

    console.log("editing price", updatePrice);
  };

    /* handles delete current security form submissions */
  handleDeleteSecurity = () => {
    const { deleteSecurity, id } = this.props;

    // toggle the pop up (close)
    this.togglePopup();

    // sends the id back to  App's "this.deleteSecurity"
    deleteSecurity(id);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="box">
        <article className="securitytable">
          <div className="title">
            <h2>
              <strong>{this.props.name}</strong>
            </h2>
            <hr className="lightgray-line" />
          </div>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td className="isin-width">{this.props.isin}</td>
                <td className="country-width">{this.props.country}</td>
                <td>
                  <button type="button" className="price-btn" onClick={this.togglePricePopup}>Prices</button>
                  {this.state.showPricePopup ? (
                    <PriceForm
                      pricelist= {this.props.price}
                      updatePrice={ this.updatePrice }
                      addPrice={this.props.addPrice}
                      closePopup= {this.togglePricePopup}
                    />
                  ) : null}
                </td>
                <td className="editing-btn">
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="edit-btn"
                    onClick={this.togglePopup}
                  >
                    Edit
                  </button>
                  {this.state.showPopup ? (
                    <SecurityForm
                      {...this.props}
                      handleEditSecuritySubmission={ this.handleEditSecuritySubmission }
                      handleDeleteSecurity={this.handleDeleteSecurity}
                      cancelPopup={this.togglePopup}
                    />
                  ) : null}
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </article>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This code in question is this list that'll open in Popup window which is a child componenet:

```
<button type="button" className="price-btn" onClick={this.togglePricePopup}>Prices</button>
                      {this.state.showPricePopup ? (
                        <PriceForm
                          pricelist= {this.props.price}
                          updatePrice={ this.updatePrice }
                          addPrice={this.props.addPrice}
                          closePopup= {this.togglePricePopup}
                        />
                      ) : null}
```

In this child component, which is Price Popup:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PriceBox from "../SinglePricebox/index";
import AddPriceForm from "../AddPriceForm/index";

export default class PriceForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      priceArr: this.props.pricelist,
      showPricePopup: false,
      addPricePopup: false,
      isToggleOn: true,
      date: props.date || "",
      number: props.number || ""
    };
  }

  updateInput = ({ target: { name, value } }) =>
  this.setState({ [name]: value });

  togglePopup = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      showPopup: !prevState.showPopup 
    }));
  };

  togglePricePopup = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      showPricePopup: !prevState.showPricePopup
    }));
  };

  addPricePopup = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      addPricePopup: !prevState.addPricePopup
    }));
  };

    /* adds a new price to the list */
    addPrice = newPrice => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        addPricePopup: !prevState.addPricePopup,
        // spreads out the previous list and adds the new price with a unique id
        priceArr: [...prevState.priceArr, { ...newPrice }]
      }));
    };

    handleListSubmit = () => {

      const { priceArr } = this.state;
      const { updatePrice } = this.props;

      const fields = {priceArr};

      this.setState(() => {
          // if (addPrice) addPrice(fields);
          updatePrice(fields);
      });
      console.log("submission", fields);
    };


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="popup">
        <div className="popup-inner">
          <div className="price-form">
            <h2>Prices</h2>
            <div className="scroll-box">
            {this.state.priceArr.map((props) => (
              <PriceBox
                {...props}
                key={props.date}
              />
            ))}
            </div>
            <div className="buttons-box flex-content-between">
              <button
                type="button"
                onClick={this.addPricePopup}
                className="btn add-button">Add +</button>
                {this.state.addPricePopup && (
                      <AddPriceForm
                        addPrice={this.addPrice}
                        cancelPopup={this.addPricePopup}
                      />
                    )}
              <div className="add-btns">
              <button
                type="button"
                onClick={this.handleListSubmit}
                className="btn cancel-button"
              >
                Close
              </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What I'm attempting to do is to send the data (the list array) back to the Parent component on close, but I notice that I can send the data back but I couldn't close the window...

```
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={this.handleListSubmit}
            className="btn cancel-button"
          >
            Close
          </button>
```

How do I do this? I cannot add something like `this.props.closePopup();` in the `handleListSubmit` function because while it can close the window, it prevents the list array from being submitted and passed to the Parent component.

Comment: Is all of this code really necessary to reproduce the problem? See [mcve]. You'll make it easier for people to help you if you have a simplified version that shows the problem very clearly. Thanks.

Comment: Really? I thought they need to see all of my code in order to understand what's going on...

Comment: Yes, it should be complete/reproducible, but it should also be minimal, that is, removes all unnecessary code which isn't relevant to recreating the problem. Please see the above link for guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parent callback function to send data from child to parent.

on child

```
handleListSubmit = () => {
...
this.props.onSummited(data)

}
```